# Some separable differential equations forego taking the absolute value of a log argument. Why and when?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Background**

Say you're solving the basic differential equation for exponential growth, and you have

$$y' = ky$$

We solve this as a separable equation, and (according to what I would do) go on as such:

$$\frac1y y' = k$$

(Then, using the "trick" of pretending the differential operator is a fraction.)

$$\int \frac1y \mathrm dy = \int k \mathrm dx$$

$$\ln|y| = kx + C$$

Now, this is where the book and I differ. In the book, the LHS is simply written as $\ln(y)$, without taking the absolute value of the argument, and failing to explain why.

My initial guess is that we can do this because we've guaranteed that $y>0$ because in a context where we use logistic growth, we start at some positive $y(0)$, and a positive proportionality constant $k$, and therefore we're guaranteed that both $y > 0$ and $y' > 0$, which eliminates the need for the absolute value.

But if I throw the equation into Wolfram Alpha, it doesn't specify this constraint, and neither do I. Regardless, it foregoes the absolute value as demonstrated here:

[image]

**Question**

Is there an underlying reason why the absolute value can be skipped for certain separable equations like this?

**Further musings**

Say we go on with the absolute value present, we would continue:

$$|y| = e^{kx}e^C$$

$$y = \pm De^{kx}, \ \ (D=e^C)$$

This is where I feel the distinction becomes important.

If $C$ is an arbitrary constant, then $D = e^C$ is an arbitrary **positive** constant. And resolving the absolute value puts a $\pm$ in front of the $D$, making it an arbitrary constant of any sign again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking anymore, it seems that your final comments answer your own question.

Comment: @StephenDonovan - Well, that's what confuses me. If we had not had the absolute value sign on the LHS, then we wouldn't have had the $\pm D$ on the RHS. It would have been a strictly positive constant. So from my perspective, the lack of absolute value on LHS gives a different answer wherein we require the constant is strictly positive. But that doesn't seem like it should be a constraint.

Comment: $|y| = C \leftrightarrow y = \pm C.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan - Yes, exactly. Having the absolute value sign gives a different answer than when you don't. So why is Wolfram Alpha, for example, not using it?

Comment: Oh okay, sorry I misunderstood your question. Did you specifically give Wolfram your initial conditions?

Comment: @StephenDonovan - No, the input was simply "y' = ky" with no other conditions. For reference: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+ky